# eclipse : treetable creating the tree from the second column

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, jtreetable

I managed to make a treetable using treeColumn() using various examples from the net and it appears like this

```
|   Column1     | Column2      |
--------------------------------
|+ColItem1      | Col2Item1    |
| -Col1subitem1 | Col2subitem2 |
|   item1       | item1        |
|   item2       | item2        |
|   item3       | item3        |
```

basically the tree is on the first column.It draws from the left.
 What i want is draw the tree from the second column like this:

```
|   Column1     | Column2        |
----------------------------------
|ColItem1      | +Col2Item1      |
|Col1subitem1  |   -Col2subitem2 |
|item1         |     item1       |
|item2         |     item2       |
|item3         |     item3       |
```

Can anyone help me accomplish this? Or is it just not possible ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree` widget this is not possible. But you could try the [Nebula Grid Component](http://eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/grid/grid.php), this is not a native widget, that has support for something..